# Cosmos db regional traffic

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have enabled Global replication for cosmos db in prod. The uri of my cosmos db is my-cosmos-db-prod.document.azure.com:port .  In Application Insight's Application Map, I am seeing traffic for 3 different endpoints.

1. my-cosmos-db-prod
2. my cosmos-db-prod-eastus
3. my-cosmos-db-prod-westus.

I don't understand why I am seeing traffic for first endpoint. Shouldn't I be seeing only regional endpoints? What region does the first endpoint represent?

Also I have enabled 5 regions but I am seeing traffic for only 2 regions(eastus, westus). For the service of my scale, I am pretty sure there has to be traffic in other regions as well. It has been just 12 hours since I added other regions and everything looks good on azure portal. Is there a delay in when we can actually start seeing traffic on newly added regions?

I am using cosmos db 3.17.1
This is how I have configured region preference in code.
.WithApplicationRegion(this.GetRegionPreference())

```
private string GetRegionPreference()
        {
            switch (this.serviceConfig.Region)
            {
                case "usea":
                    return Regions.EastUS;
                case "uswe":
                    return Regions.WestUS;
                case "asea":
                    return Regions.EastAsia;
                case "asse":
                    return Regions.SoutheastAsia;
                case "euno":
                    return Regions.NorthEurope;
                case "euwe":
                    return Regions.WestEurope;
                default:
                    return Regions.WestUS;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What SDK are you using to connect?

Comment: This article explains the routing the SDK does based on the configuration you are provinding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-sdk-availability

Are you setting a regional preference in your SDK configuration?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos Version="3.17.1"

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I have updated my answer. Can you please check.

Comment: Normally the SDK will always use 1 region, the one that matches your ApplicationRegion. The cases where it might go to another one are documented in the link I shared. The SDK will not use all regions, that is not how it works. If you want to have global coverage you should take a look at architectures like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally where you have multiple apps with different configuration, and each app will reach one of the regions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Matias.

According to your description, [the sdk you used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-multi-master?tabs=api-async#netv3) is needed to set `ApplicationRegion` and this parameter decides which region your program will be deployed.

And to explain why you only see traffic for 3 different endpoints while you seems to set some other regions, I think it's based on the rule of cosmosdb. For lower latency, cosmosdb will use a closer endpoint to provide service.

> To lower the latency, place the data close to where your users are.
> Choosing the required regions depends on the global reach of your
> application and where your users are located. Cosmos DB transparently
> replicates the data to all the regions associated with your Cosmos
> account.